# Save a photo selected from gallery to cache directory

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I've written a method that creates a directory in my apps cache directory and then prompts the user to take a photo or select a photo from the gallery.

if the user takes a new photo, the photo is saved to the cache as profile.jpg

I'm trying to get the intent that returns a photo from the gallery to save the returned photo in the cache directory of my app as profile.jpg.

I'm having trouble achieving this.

```
public void selectImage(View v) {

        File newDir = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), "RecruitSwift");
        if(!newDir.isDirectory())
            newDir.mkdirs();
        else
            Toast.makeText(this, "Dir already exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if(newDir.canWrite())
            imageFile = new File(newDir, "profile.jpg");
        else
            Toast.makeText(this, "Dir not writable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        final CharSequence[] options = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery","Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserProfileInterviewScreenActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (options[item].equals("Take Photo")){
                    Intent takeProfileImage = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    if (takeProfileImage.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {

                        Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
                        takeProfileImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                        startActivityForResult(takeProfileImage, 1);
                    }
                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")){
                    Intent takeProfileImage = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                    Uri selectedImage = takeProfileImage.getData();
                    imageFile = selectedImage;
                    startActivityForResult(takeProfileImage, 2);

                }
                else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem exactly? If you pick a picture from the Gallery you get a content provider path which you can convert to a file system path.

Comment: in the else if(Choose From Gallery") section of the code, I want to get the returned gallery photo and save a new copy of it in the directory I'v created at the start of the method.

Comment: That is impossible as there is nothing returned there. And as said: you will later not get a photo but a path once the user picked a picture.

Comment: Can I, as you said, convert the content provider path into a file system path and then use that file system path to create a new file (copy) in the directory I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take a photo or pick a picture, you need to call `startActivityForResult` and then override `onActivityResult`. Here are some codes to take a photo, take a look:

`startActivityForResult`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
intent.putExtra("return-data", false);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(AVATAR_FILE_TMP));
intent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", true);
startActivityForResult(intent, CODE_TAKE_PHOTO);
```

then override `onActivityResult`:

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CODE_TAKE_PHOTO) {
            cropImage(Uri.fromFile(AVATAR_FILE_TMP));
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why this is the accepted answer. This doesn't explain how to pick a picture from gallery and save it into the cache dir.

Comment: @Bevor Just try this code. This `startActivityForResult` method will pop up gallery.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @greenapps  the intent it's self doesn't return anything, you have to get the returned content provider path in your onActivityResult method and convert it into a file system path.

This is the code I wrote in the end:

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                c.close();
                Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                Log.w("path of profileImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                try{
                    String file_path = getExternalCacheDir() + "/MyWebsiteDir";
                    File dir = new File(file_path);
                    if(!dir.exists())
                        dir.mkdirs();
                    File file = new File(dir, "profile.jpg");
                    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
                    fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```